# Как исключть поля из json при анмаршалинге в Golang

Tags: golang

у меня есть json с плавающим количеством полей, анмаршалится в мапу

```
var data map[string]string
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
```

Как можно исключить некоторые поля чтобы их не было в получившейся мапе?

Comment: Удалите поля после Unmarshal. Если вы заранее знаете структуру JSON, то можете написать кастомную струкуру с необходимыми полями, и парсить в значение этого типа. Парсер проигнорирует поля, не указанные в структуре.

Comment: Так же, можете реальзовать пользовательскую имплементациюю Unmarshal, которая будет игнорировать поля, которые вы хотите исключить.